# Visual Studio Xml comments plugins

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

Does anyone know if there exists a Visual Studio(2010) addin/plugin that can help with managing xml documentation comments ?

Features I'm looking for:

- being able to hide/show xml comments in the code (scrolling through it makes me want to hit my laptop with a hammer)
- some GUI for editing those comments and an indicator which methods/classes are already documented - like an icon/color change/sth
- make it easy to build documentation eg. html/pdf/...
- anything else that can help

I'm not sure if this question fits on Stackoverflow, but I wasn't able to find a more suitable Stackexchange site for this and since questions can be moved between sites please move it if it's not in the right place.

Comment: Please consider moving to programmers stackexchange

Comment: @Marcel this question doesn't look like a good fit for Programmers.SE, check their [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

I use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) to help write the comments and [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) (w/ [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) as the GUI frontend) to generate html documents from the xml comments.